# Flink1.32 akka.tcp

Tags: akka, apache-flink

When I start the cluster,the log in TaskManager like this:

> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 1, timeout: 500
>   milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 2, timeout:
>   1000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 3, timeout:
>   2000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 4, timeout:
>   8000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 5, timeout:
>   16000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 6, timeout:
>   30000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 7, timeout:
>   30000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 8, timeout:
>   30000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 9, timeout:
>   30000 milliseconds)
>
> INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -
>   Trying to register at JobManager
>   akka.tcp://flink@master1:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 10, timeout:
>   30000 milliseconds)

It seems can not get connction with JobManger,Bu the web Ui can see the TaskManager.
When I submit a Job to the cluster, JobManager get some error log:

> Caused by
>   :akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException:Recipient[Actor[akka://flink/deadLetters]]
>   had already been terminated

I guess akka got some error,but I do not know how to solve it.
many thanks for helping me

Comment: Who did you start your cluster? Are you able to access the master from the taskmanagers host (e.g. `telnet master1 6123` should work)?

Comment: cluster has started,I can see the TaskManagers in the web UI，TaskManager also can telnet master1 6123 success。But the taskManager in the web UI seems not right ,the Tab <Task Managers>  ,title <Path,ID>  row is akka://flink/deadLetters  not the right Ip and port

Comment: How does the JobManager log looks like? If you can at least see something at the web UI it means that the JobManager knows something about the task manager.

Comment: My cluster is standalone model.
the last log show like this:        
----                                               
Register TaskManager at slaves_03 (akka://flink/deadLetters) as  87xxxxxxxx4d. Current number of registered hosts is 4.Current number of alive task slots is 24
Register TaskManager at slaves_04 (akka://flink/deadLetters) as  51xxxxxxxx5c. Current number of registered hosts is 4.Current number of alive task slots is 32
----
I think the error is <akka://flink/deadLetters>
but the flink-conf.yaml in my test cluster is the same to the work cluster.The network is available

Comment: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/%3CCADuRPDuTGMYTtoGevV5mfvZedS1OxB35+hoiJQ96oDLhjNmm6Q@mail.gmail.com%3E     I found this,the same error to me ,but I do everything like this ,it does not metter

Comment: Good point @LiuZhuo - what does the job actually does? Does the job fail or gets canceled because there are not enough task-manager slots available?

Answer (score 2):

Finally,I solved this problem myself. There is a bug at flink 1.3.x, your cluster host must not contain special characters.

In my production environment, the hosts are called "flink_master" "slaves_01" "slaves_02". The "_" caused this problem. It seems like you are only allowed to use alphanumeric and numeric characters. When I change the hosts to "master" "salves1" "slaves2" it works well.

Comment: Nice finding. Is there already a bug at the flink bug-database? If not feel free to create one: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK/issues/FLINK-8976?filter=allopenissues

The flink guys are really nice and always happy to help ;-)